# How to transfer GPG key to another computer

Tags: 20.04, encryption, windows-10, gnupg, openpgp

I generated the OpenPGP key on my Windows computer. I don't know why I didn't do it on Ubuntu. How do I get the key from that computer onto Ubuntu? Do I need to generate a new key?

Comment: You did no research at all. All I had to do was using your title search google and it gave me this url https://makandracards.com/makandra-orga/37763-gpg-extract-private-key-and-import-on-different-machine

Comment: If you still have access to your Windows computer, export your keys (e.g. to a flash drive) and then import them into you Ubuntu system.